# Python: Output of text file using sys.argv

Tags: python, function, if-statement, text-files, sys

I'm writing a code where I'm supposed to use "sys.argv" to read a text file. I want two different outputs depending on the input arguments. If the argument in the terminal is only "message.txt" I want the output to be:

```
Anna
Hello Everyone
Kalle
Hi there
Anna
Coffee break?
Pelle
Absolutely
Kalle
Sure
Anna
Great, see you downstairs in 5 minutes
```

But if the input is both "Lab2_1.py" and "message.txt" I want to send the text file to a function where it prints another output. The function works, I've tried it before.

I'm thinking some sort of if-statement for the input arguments but I can't get it to work. My main function now that sends the argument to the function is (this works the way I want it to):

```
messages = read_file(sys.argv[1])
name1 = input('Enter a name to search for: \n')
display_entry(name1, messages)
```

I was thinking something like this (doesn't work):

```
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    messages = read_file(sys.argv)
    print(messages)

else:
    messages = read_file(sys.argv)
    name1 = input('Enter a name to search for: \n')
    display_entry(name1, messages)
```

So that the first statement will print only the text file in its "original" form, like the first code block above, and the other statement will send the text file to a function and create another output. There will be maximum 2 arguments in the terminal.

Any ideas on how I can fix this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html)

> argv[0] is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether this is a full > pathname or not)

So `if len(sys.argv) == 1:` will always evaluate to `True`.

Changing to `if len(sys.argv) == 2:` should help.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately it still doesn't work even if I try to change the arguments position...

Answer (score 0):

The first item of `sys.argv` is always the name of the python file that is being executed. That means that `len(sys.argv) == 1` will be true even if no arguments are given.

To fix this you want to check if `len(sys.argv) == 2` or `3`:

```
if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    print("target file: " + sys.argv[1])
    # do stuff here

elif len(sys.argv) == 3:
    if "foo.py" in sys.argv and "text.txt" in sys.argv:
        name = input("put name here:\n ")
        # do stuff with the name
```

Comment: Thanks! The first "if" works now but the second one still doesn't... I get this output when searching for Annas messages: 82074eaff0445f8b3ef3ebd333b20c2/.2f2dcd8726f74a8a82379c0b11b5cde9//lab2_1.txt

My second "if" looks like this:
    elif len(sys.argv) == 3:
        if 'Lab2_1.py' in sys.argv and 'lab2_1.txt' in sys.argv:
            messages = read_file(sys.argv[2])
            name1 = input('Enter a name to search for: \n')
            display_entry(name1, messages)

Comment: That is perhaps a problem with your `read_file()` or your `display_entry()` functions

Comment: That's true! I will take a look at it, thanks :)